Tricky constraint in Functions + PnC
Let $A$ be set of first $7$ natural numbers and $B$ be set of first $6$ even natural numbers. Consider function $f: A \to B$ such that $$f(x) \neq 2x \qquad\forall x \in A$$ and $f(x)$ is an onto function. If the total number of such functions is $181 \times N$, then what is the sum of digits of $N$?
Guys, I got the number of total functions as $6^7$ but then was confused about how to subtract the number of onto functions here. Please guide.

Are you familiar with the Inclusion-Exclusion Priniciple?
